# Where did the angle convention originate?

Tags: math-history

Where did the angle convention (in mathematics) come from?

One would imagine that a clockwise direction would be more 'natural' (given
sundials & the like, also a magnetic compass dial).

Also, given time and direction conventions, one would imagine that the
zero degree line would be vertical.

There are two parts to this
question: (1) Why do we measure angles anticlockwise?
(2) Why do we take the zero degree line to be along the $x$-axis.

(This was inspired by https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/9874/why-do-we-conventionally-treat-trig-functions-as-going-anti-clockwise-from-the-r.)

Comment: I don't know the history but now I'm curious too - good question! Before Descartes, presumably there was already a standard depiction of the number system as a horizontal line, with direction of increase being to the right as that's the direction of writing in Europe. (In versions of software localized for Semitic languages, the direction of increase is R->L, and e.g. the order of "OK Cancel" buttons gets reversed.) Perhaps Descartes built upon the existing 1D portrayal and used the next available dimension. Whether here or in Arabia, the vertical direction of increase is up, not down. (cont)

Comment: @BrianO: The cultural aspect never occurred to me!

Comment: Given that orientation, and sin, cos and tan being what they are, it seems the direction of increase for angles has to go from $\theta=0$ at $(1,0)$ to $0 < \theta < \frac {\pi} 2$ in the first quadrant -- hence, counterclockwise. // This all sounds plausible, anyway to me(!)... but take with a boulder of salt: I've never read Descartes on analytic geometry, nor checked out manuscripts of Nicolas of Cusa, etc.

Comment: @BrianO sounds very plausible.

Comment: This question has essentially been asked and answered on [hsm.se] over [here](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/3006/26).  The post there was inspired by the same ME.SE post. I suggest to merge this post with the HSM post.

Comment: @Danu: Thanks for the link; I did a fairly extensive search beforehand but HSM never appeared. The linked question has some plausible reasoning, but I am looking for something more definitive, if such a thing exists.

Comment: @Danu. I don't think there is a way to merge questions across sites.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That could be true: Perhaps, then, a migration? What do you think, @copper.hat?

Comment: @Danu: I have no objection, albeit do not see a problem with it remaining here either.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Why another downvote?

Answer (score 5):

This is by no means answering the question as it is. However, It is just to give a historical piece (taken from "[The history of Stokes' Theorem](http://www.ingelec.uns.edu.ar/asnl/Materiales/Cap03Extras/Stokes-Katz.pdf)" written by Katz) that might come handy when thinking of the first part of the question (CW vs. CCW or ACW).

[image]

As it can be seen, Green's theorem as introduced by Cauchy is undecided about the orientation of the curve.

I repeat that I didn't attempt to answer the question as asked. I just try to extend the question a bit hoping that it helps us to find the answer (if any) to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

We measure the angles with the $x$-axis. So one of the arm of the angle is $x$-axis and the other arm is also on $x$-axis if the angle is zero. This is why we take zero degree line along the $x$-axis.

In rectangular coordinate system we have four quadrants. Now we move the second arm which is fixed to the origin. When we move the second arm in counter clockwise direction then we have pattern of going from quadrant I-II-III-IV.

In history mathematicians worked on height and distance problems in which they were required to find height of a tower(say) without directly measuring it. In those problems they required to find the angle between the line of sight(seeing the highest point on the tower) and the surface of Earth. This means we go counter clockwise for measuring the angle.

Today we have coordinate transformation so we can always define everything in new coordinate system according to are convenience.

In my class text book of mathematics while doing trigonometry I found this problem and I searched for the solution. Above thing is what I got while searching for the solution.

Comment: I would suspect that the sun and astronomy would have had a greater influence on convention. In any case, the above doesn't show why you would measure angles in an anticlockwise manner.

Answer (score 1):

It is perhaps "natural" to adopt these two conventions:

1. The zero angle "should" correspond to the positive $x$-axis.
2. Small but positive angles "should" be in the quadrant where $x$ and $y$ are positive.

Given that we also adopt the convention that the $x$-axis points rightwards and the $y$-axis points upwards, the anticlockwise convention then also necessarily follows.